Show that estimator $\hat{\sigma}^2$ of $\sigma^2$ is unbiased.
For the linear model $y_i=2+\beta_1\exp(x_i)+\varepsilon_i$ for $i=1,...,n$ where $\beta_1$ is an unknown slope parameter, and errors $\varepsilon_i$ are uncorrelated
with zero mean and common variance $\sigma^2$, I am required to show that the estimator $\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{\sum^{n}_{i=1}(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2}{n-1}$ is unbiased for $\sigma^2$. Somehow, after a lot of work, I have ended up showing that it is biased. I've checked through my work and everything seems logical. I'm not sure if I have reasoned incorrectly, or have just missed something along the way. Could someone please point me in the correct direction. Here is what I have so far:
For $i=1,...,n$, we first note that
\begin{equation} \notag
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2] 
&=\mathbb{E}[(2+\beta_1\exp(x_i)+\varepsilon_i-(2+b_1\exp(x_i)))^2]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[(\varepsilon_i-(b_1-\beta_1)\exp(x_i))^2] \\
&=\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_i^2)-2\exp(x_i)\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_i(b_1-\beta_1))+\exp^2(x_i)\mathbb{E}((b_1-\beta_1)^2).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Since all errors $\varepsilon_i$ are independent of $b_1$ with $\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_i)=0$ and hence $Var(\varepsilon_i)=\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_i^2)=\sigma^2$, we can then write
\begin{equation} \notag
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2] 
&=\sigma^2-2\exp(x_i)\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_i)\mathbb{E}(b_1-\beta_1)+\exp^2(x_i)\mathbb{E}((b_1-\beta_1)^2) \\
&=\sigma^2+\exp^2(x_i)\mathbb{E}((b_1-\beta_1)^2).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and hence
\begin{equation} \notag
\begin{split}
\sum^{n}_{i=1}\mathbb{E}[(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2]
&=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\left(\sigma^2+\exp^2(x_i)\mathbb{E}((b_1-\beta_1)^2)\right) \\
&=n\sigma^2+\mathbb{E}((b_1-\beta_1)^2)\sum^{n}_{i=1}\exp^2(x_i) \\
&=n\sigma^2+Var(b_1)\sum^{n}_{i=1}\exp^2(x_i) \\
&=n\sigma^2+\sigma^2.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
(I showed, in a previous part, that $Var(b_1)=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum^{n}_{i=1}\exp^2(x_i)}$)
Finally, we can conclude that $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ because
\begin{equation} \notag
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}(\hat{\sigma}^2)
&=\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{\sum^{n}_{i=1}(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2}{n-1}\right) \\
&=\frac{\sum^{n}_{i=1}\mathbb{E}[(y_i-\hat{y_i})^2]}{n-1} \\
&=\frac{n+1}{n-1}\sigma^2???
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The flaw in your argument is here:

Since all errors $\varepsilon_i$ are independent of $b_1$

$\varepsilon_i$ is not independent of $b_1$. Check the expression you've derived for $b_1$, you'll see it depends on $e_i$.

I see. Thank you. I will try to find the correct expression for $\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_i(b_1-\beta_1))$
